# Packages, Ubuntu counterparts of Gentoo's useful commands

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get, gentoo, aptitude

Trying to learn how to work with packages in Ubuntu (and have Gentoo experience). This command is already known:

```
(1) sudo apt-get install pkgname
```

Looking for counterparts of these:

```
(2) emerge -s pkgname
(3) equery files pkgname
(4) equery belongs filename
(5) cat /var/lib/portage world
```

Which useful (console) package commands do you use in Ubuntu? Links to Ubuntu packages tutorial in style of Gentoo's Handbook?

Answer (score 2):

This would be the equivalent commands in Ubuntu:

- `apt-cache search package`
- `dpkg -L package`
- `dpkg -S filename`
- `aptitude search ~n.*`

Answer (score 0):

This question is better suited for superuser.com or https://askubuntu.com/.

Anyway, I haven't used Gentoo's tools, but I think [this **Debian** guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/FAQ/ch-pkgtools.en.html) on package management is quite complete and you'll find the equivalents.

Some examples on apt-get:

`apt-cache search package` queries the repo for `package`.

`apt-cache show package` displays info on a certain package (dependencies and such).

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu Hacks/Package Management](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Ubuntu_Hacks/Package_Management#Manage_Packages_from_the_Command_Line) - Manage Packages From the Command Line

[Debian Reference](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/reference/ch02.en.html#_basic_package_management_operations) - Basic package management tools: apt-get / apt-cache and aptitude.